# Check nested dictionary inside null value

Tags: objective-c

```
"data": {
        "assetID": "VMSA0000000000310652",
        "lastModified": null,
        "locale": {
          "MetadataAlbum": {
            "Artists": {
              "Artist": {
                "ArtistName": "Various Artists",
                "ArtistRole": null
              }
            },
            "Publishable": "true",
            "genres": {
              "genre": {
                "extraInfos": null,
              }
            },
```

I am getting randomly `null` value from JSON. I wan t to delete that key which value is `null` or `nil`

Comment: In ObjC the equivalent of `null` is `[NSNull null]`

Comment: For example, `string` is a field of your dictionary with type `NSString` and it maybe `null`. You should check it by `[dictionary[@"string"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]` before using. Same with `NSNumber` or another type. The condition will return `NO` if `dictionary[@"string"]` is `null` or doesn't exist.

Comment: after getting data I saved in `NSUserDefault` so it's getting crash. so need to check all value for key. I am getting up to 100 keys and values with nested dictionary.

Comment: @RahulParikh No need to check all of them. Just check before using any value.

Comment: when I am getting null value in dictionaries, after that try to add in `NsUserdefault` I am getting error like this.
[User Defaults] Attempt to set a non-property-list object

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing is not a NSDictionary but a JSON string. First of all it should be deserialized into an object with a structure coherent with it, and then used accordingly (for example using [NSJsonSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsjsonserialization)).
If for any reason the deserialization isn't necessary, you can treat it as a string and add it as a value, like:

```
[NSUserDefaults setObject:myJSON forKey:@"JSONString"]
```

where myJSON is the whole JSON string